# XNA and Silverlight for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, xna, windows-phone-8.1

So I installed XNA 4 refresh for Visual Studio 2013 ultimate with update 3 and I have this problem: when I try to make an XNA and Silverlight game or simply a Windows Phone Game, I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJk5K.png

Clicking OK gets me to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pu0P.png

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the XNA but with no success. Can someone help me?

Comment: I believe Microsoft is moving away from XNA http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207003(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: It's been a while since I last tried it, but I remember it worked fine for me. Do you have the WP developer tools installed?

Comment: the wp 8.1 developer tools are included in VS 2013 update 3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error,
it is very annoying but try this it helped me:

- Deinstall `Xna`
- And then install the `2013` version  from [this link](https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230)
  with everything wich is
  in there (read the readme cause it has to be full installed)